# Matching string with wildcard character

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I've the following code:

```
string d = "OR.ISSUE226568";
string p;
switch (d)
{
   case "VOID":
     p = "VOID";                        
     break;

   case "OR.*":
     p = "Reissue";
     break;
}
```

The problem is that right now the second case is not working.

I need something that can act as a wildcard character so that any "OR.ISSUE1234567" could be identified and the proper value assigned to the p variable.

So if d begins with "OR." the value of p will be "Reissue".

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Have you heard of Regular Expressions? That would give you a more general approach to match patterns.  If it's this simple, `p.StartsWith("OR.")` would do. You can't use a switch with either, however.

Comment: It's kinda obvious that the answer is no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like RegEx is a much better approach. With RegEx you are able to use wildcards and it can be pretty powerful. If you add "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;" you will be able to accesses it. Below is a sample. There are a bunch of websites out there that you can find on Google that will explain different symbols and how to build the matching patterns.

```
        string d = "OR.ISSUE226568";
        string p;

        if (Regex.IsMatch(d, "^OR.*$"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worked!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either switch to using a conditional instead of a switch statement:

```
if (d == "VOID") 
{
    p = "VOID";
}
else if (d.StartsWith("OR."))
{
    p = "Reissue";
}
```

Or you could look at using a Regex to match your string if you want to do something more complicated with it (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `switch` block with a wildcard (or for example regexes). But according to your question, you can do this:

```
string d = "OR.ISSUE226568";
if(d.StartsWith("OR."))
    d = d.Remove(3);
string p;
switch (d)
{
   case "VOID":
     p = "VOID";                        
     break;

   case "OR.":
     p = "Reissue";
     break;

   // other cases...
}
```

But since you have only tow `case` statement, there is no need to `switch` at all. Using `if/else` is more easier and makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have *starts with* type of checks to support and you might need changing them at runtime you can use a dictionary:

```
string d = "OR.ISSUE226568";
//string d= "VOID";
// Dictionary with start of the string
var target = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
  {"VOID","Void"},
  {"OR.", "Reissue"}
};

// find the one that matches
var p = (from kv in target
        where d.StartsWith(kv.Key)
        select kv.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```